# Very slow to make relationship between the nodes in py2neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I have more than 50,000 nodes called as weblogs and I am trying to connect two node with respect to its property, my code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from py2neo import neo4j, Node, Relationship, Graph, GraphError
from py2neo.packages.httpstream import http

http.socket_timeout = 99999
graph = Graph()
relation_counter = 0
for node in graph.find("Weblogs"):

    matches = graph.match(start_node=node, rel_type="hasDirectLinks")
    if not matches:
        continue


        for relation in matches:

            for weblog_node in graph.find("Weblogs", "entry_url", relation.end_node.properties["url"]):

               if weblog_node:
                   graph.create_unique(Relationship(node, "hasDirectLinks", weblog_node))
                   relation_counter += 1 
                   if relation_counter % 30 == 0:
                       print (relation_counter, ": Numbers of Relationship made")


print (relation_counter, ": Total numbers of relationship made")
```

Code is working fine but it is very slow, is there any suggestions to make it faster ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow dude, you're working really hard here to try to do something (I think) is fairly simple.   :)   Yeah I think you can improve on this!

It seems like you're trying to match certain kinds of weblog patterns, then create new direct relationships between indirectly related weblogs.  Is that right?

I've tried to reformulate your code as a single cypher query.  Py2neo already [lets you execute cypher directly](http://py2neo.org/2.0/cypher.html), so I would carefully double/triple check this query, and then run something similar to it.  It would replace all of the code you pasted.

```
MATCH (blog:Weblogs)-[matches:hasDirectLinks]->(somethingElse)
WITH matches, blog, somethingElse
MATCH (weblog_node:Weblogs)
WHERE weblog_node.entry_url = somethingElse.url
MERGE (blog)-[newRel:hasDirectLinks]->(weblog_node)
RETURN count(newRel);
```

(I named variables the same as what your python was doing so hopefully this is easier to follow)

Your code is running really slowly because you're connecting to a REST endpoint, and doing a lot of individual fetches of relationships, and individual scans of nodes with certain labels.  This means your code spends a lot of time going back and forth to the server.  If instead of manually programming which relationships get created, you use cypher, then you can do all of the nodes and all of the relationships in a single query.  Once to the server and back, and you're done.

I'm betting doing this as a single cypher query is probably going to be many dozens of times faster.

Cypher is your friend!  If you learn it, you're going to save yourself a lot of coding!

Happy trails!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying but one concern in the Cypher Query you posted; entry_url is a property of a Weblogs it is not a relationship.

Comment: I just updated the cypher query to use property matching instead, but the concept is still the same.  If this cypher still isn't correct, then think it through carefully and write your own query, but basically the answer to your question is "replace all of your python code with one cypher query, and things will run much faster".

Comment: The Cypher query performs fine till the where clause for equality check but when it reaches the merge it is running forever.

Comment: How many `Weblogs` nodes do you have?  Have you created an index on `Weblogs:entry_url`?  (You should)  This query is trying to compare most weblogs to most other weblogs, which could be a lot of comparisons if the number of records is large.

Comment: I have around 80,000 Weblogs, yes it is quite large.

Comment: So look at your query, and no matter what you do it's not going to be fast.  You're comparing 80,000 weblogs to potentially 80,000 others.  Do the math, that's a lot.  You can simplify the query like I said, but the cypher isn't going to run really fast either because of the sheer number.

Comment: The performance was blazingly fast after I indexed the node Weblog and its property source_url. Thanks a lot for good insight about cypher and rephrasing all my program with cypher . I accept your answer.

Comment: +1 for this answer. The high level py2neo API were designed for ease of use, not speed. Cypher is the correct way to go for more complex use cases and you should always look to minimise the number of server requests that are made if performance is a consideration.

Comment: Cypher (embedded) queries through py2neo seem to time out and same queries run fast in Cypher command prompt. So I guess it may be a good practice to do DDL in cypher directly and do manipulation on graphs using py2neo. Correct my if I am wrong.